# Building Lexical Analyzer using lex tool

Tags: compiler-construction, lex, flex-lexer

I am trying to learn how to use the lex tool to create a Lexical Analyzer. Now I've downloaded a couple of files that says LEX or FLEX but I am having trouble even starting them and the best part, the website doesn't explain it at all. Then I tried googling for any lex tool that may help me build a Lexical Analyzer I keep getting flex by adobe to create mobile apps.
Now my Question is two fold Where can I find a Lex tool to start working and can I get any tutorials (IDE based or not) just for me to start doing something.
Thanks.

Comment: http://flex.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Marcin Łoś    I got the files but how can I use them to create a lexical analyzer? Are there any tutorials?

Comment: Sure, I can't really recommend anything specific, but googling "lex tutorial" seems to yield sensible results. For example, http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/download/LexAndYaccTutorial.pdf seems fine (haven't read it all, though)

Comment: Yes, Tom Niemann's tutorial that Marcin Łoś gave a link to is a good introduction, and I always recommend it to my students in the compiler course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered in the comments by @Marcin Łoś and @Thomas Padron-McCarthy, but remains in the unanswered question queue.

(See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The Flex lexical analyser can be downloaded (both as source or binary) from https://github.com/westes/flex/releases

There are many good online tutorials you can find by internet search. This one: http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/download/LexAndYaccTutorial.pdf was recommended. I also like this one: http://aquamentus.com/flex_bison.html

There are also many helpful demonstrations on YouTube.